# How to modify attribute ROWSPAN with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td rowspan="3">ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td class="remove">22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td class="remove">22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td rowspan="3">ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td class="remove">22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td class="remove">22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td rowspan="3">ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td class="remove">22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td class="remove">22</td></tr>
</table>

$('.remove').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r5BDW/1/

If I remove TR then table is breaks because ROWSPAN is too large. Is possible modify ROWSPAN? If yes, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 $('.remove').click(function(){
     $(this).parent()
            .prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
            .find('td[rowspan]')
            .attr('rowspan', function(i, rs) { return rs - 1; })
            .end()
            .end()
            .remove();
 });
```

- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)
- [`element-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- [`has-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)
- [`has-attribute-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)
- [`first-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)
- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)
- [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 5):

I would expect the attr() method to work... try this:

```
$('selector for the element you want to modify').attr('rowspan', 'newvalue');
```

For example:

```
$('#myCell').attr('rowspan', '2');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you need it, I've written a function which automatically detects repeated names in a column and adds rowspan. You just need to supply a column (array of td values).

```js
var column1 = $('.modified_table td:first-child');
var column2 = $('.modified_table td:nth-child(2)');
var column3 = $('.modified_table td:nth-child(3)');

modifyTableRowspan(column1);
modifyTableRowspan(column2);
modifyTableRowspan(column3);

function modifyTableRowspan(column) {

        var prevText = "";
        var counter = 0;

        column.each(function (index) {


            var textValue = $(this).text();

            if (index === 0) {
                prevText = textValue; 
            }
            
            if (textValue !== prevText || index === column.length - 1) {

                var first = index - counter;

                if (index === column.length - 1) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }

                column.eq(first).attr('rowspan', counter);


                if (index === column.length - 1)
                {
                    for (var j = index; j > first; j--) {
                        column.eq(j).remove();
                    }
                }

                else {

                    for (var i = index - 1; i > first; i--) {
                        column.eq(i).remove();
                    }
                }

                prevText = textValue;
                counter = 0;
            }

            counter++;

        });

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>

Before:
<table class="unmodified_table" border="1">
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>abs</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>abs</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>abs</td></tr>
</table>
<br /> </br>

After:
<table class="modified_table" border="1">
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>abs</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>abs</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>ads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>abs</td></tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ewk227x/2/

Comment: Is it just me, or does your before and after example have exactly the same elements? :)

Comment: I thought this routine would be perfect for what I needed, but on further testing this code seems to have a problem with the last row. see https://jsfiddle.net/eupb0fmx/3/

Comment: The question on this subject I posted here has a better solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67324092/javascript-to-create-table-row-spans-on-the-fly